# Delete with inner join across 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have three tables one of this storing users basic information, the other one is profile information and the last one is storing user picture.

When i deleting these user i need to delete all of the data in these tables. So i write a query like this.

```
DELETE Kullanicilar FROM Kullanicilar 
INNER JOIN ProfilBilgileri ON Kullanicilar.ID = ProfilBilgileri.UyeID 
INNER JOIN UyeResim ON Kullanicilar.ID = UyeResim.UyeID 
WHERE Kullanicilar.ID=@ID
```

But it just deleting the data from "Kullanicilar" table.
Any suggestions?

EDIT : I'm using MSSQL 2008 but hosting firm 2000 so i need compatible code.

Comment: Some peoples saying using trigger is risky so i didnt use.

Comment: `sql` is a generic tag, do you mean `sql` `sql-server` ?

Comment: You could look into cascading deletes on your foreign keys. Otherwise you would need 3 different `delete` statements (except in MySQL I think where you can specify multiple tables in a `DELETE` I believe...)

Comment: Triggers are not risky if you use them correctly. Anyone who tells you this is simply an incompetent database developer. But they are like any other code, they can have bugs and those bugs can be critical so they need to be extensively tested.  They are good tools for many purposes, they are the wrong tool for this though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a trigger like Xavinou sugested or, if you have foreign keys in your tables, you can go with Delete on Cascade option. Your foreign keys will be created using this:

```
FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES AnotherTable
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: I'm not using Foreign keys but this is a other solution.

Comment: if you don't have foreign keys then setting them up would be the first thing!

Comment: Oh I was already have foreign keys one of them. Now i created on the other now i will try this code.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you, you just saved me hours!

Answer (score 4):

The solution that springs to mind is to use a transaction.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE FROM Kullanicilar WHERE ID = @ID
DELETE FROM ProfilBilgileri WHERE UyeID = @ID
DELETE FROM UyeResim WHERE UyeID = @ID

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Except you should never write a transaction without a TRY CATCH block to rollback if one of the actions fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @pbid int
declare @urid int    
SELECT @pbid = ProfilBilgileri.UyeID, @urid = UyeResim.UyeID FROM Kullanicilar INNER JOIN ProfilBilgileri ON Kullanicilar.ID = ProfilBilgileri.UyeID INNER JOIN UyeResim ON Kullanicilar.ID = UyeResim.UyeID WHERE Kullanicilar.ID=@ID

delete Kullanicilar where ID = @ID
delete ProfilBilgileri where UyeID = @pbid
delete UyeResim where UyeID = @urid
```

Of course, I'm assuming that there's a 1-to-1 correspondence between Kullanicilar and the other two tables.  If it's 1-to-many, you'll need a temp table for each of the other tables and delete based on that.  Hope this points you in the right direction!